# Usando PHP no terminal, xampp

Tags: php, osx, xampp

Estou tentando usar o PHP através do terminal, mas não consigo, quando eu digito `which php` ele retorna `/usr/bin/php` aí por isso não consigo executar arquivos PHP, por que ele não encontra os arquivos.

Estou usando XAMPP para MAC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na raiz da sua pasta de usuário, `~`, tem um arquivo chamado `.bash_profile`. Acrescente o seguinte no final dele:

```bsh
export PATH="/applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

Salve o arquivo e reinicie o terminal. Agora o `which php` deve indicar o php-cli do XAMPP.

---

**Alternativa #1**

Para chamar um executável de um diretório específico, basta digitar o caminho completo até ele. Em vez de

```bsh
php meuscript.php
```

usar assim:

```bsh
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php meuscript.php
```

**Alternativa #2**

Navegando para a pasta onde fica o PHP do XAMPP, e rodando a partir de lá:

```bsh
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
php meuarquivo.php
```

Comment: como eu encontro e acrescento? não sou familiarizada

Comment: que editor de código você usa?

Comment: eu utilizo o Brackets

Comment: No brackets, digite ⌘+O, navegue para sua pasta de usuário (a que tem o seu nome, na barra da esquerda), e escolha o arquivo `.bash_profile`. Se ele não existir ali, crie um com esse nome.

Comment: Uma dúvida extra, eu incluo vários arquivos no meu `meuarquivo.php (require)` quando acesso ele na web roda normalmente mas quando é pelo terminal ele não encontra os arquivos... isso tem lógica?

Comment: É melhor você fazer uma pergunta separada sobre isso, @Elaine. Pode ter a ver com a configuração do PHP.